# Minimize Number- c++

Tags: c++, arrays

how can I Print the maximum possible number of operations that can be performed?

The operation is as follows: if all numbers are even then divide each of them by 2 otherwise, you can not perform any more operations.

First line contains a number N (1 ≤ N ≤ 200) number of elements.

Second line contains N numbers (1  ≤  A I  ≤  109).

Examples

Input

3

8 12 40

Output

2

Input

4

5 6 8 10

Output

0

I will write the cod in the comment cause I don't know how to put it here ..can you please edit it for me?

I know my code is wrong but I can't fix it so please explain it for me .

Comment: `for(int v=a[i];v!=x&&0<=x<=100000;v++)` -- Explain how this loop operates.  It is hard enough to read without whitespace, and even if it contained whitespace, that `0<=x<=100000` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also using `break;` unconditionally in loops looks weird.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n,sum=0,arr[200];
cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
cin>>arr[i];
while(arr[i]%2==0)
{
arr[i]=arr[i]/2;
sum++;
}
}
cout<<sum;
return 0;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking 'x' with n and m, but it has to be at end.
Also just use an 'index' variable to keep track of where to insert in your array. And then use the same 'index' while finding the 'x'.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[100000],n,m,x;
    cin>>n>>m;
    bool flag=0;
    int index =0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
            cin >> a[index];
            index++;
        }
    }
    cin >>x;
    for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
        if(x==a[i]) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0){
        cout<<"will not take number";
    } else if(flag==1){
        cout<<"will take number";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<n && 2<=n<=100 ;i++) {
```

`2<=n<=100` is not doing what you mean. It evaluates to `(2 <= n) <= 100)` which is a different check.

You need to do:

```
2 <= n && n <= 100
```

You need to fix the other checks where you are doing this as well.

Also, since `n` is not being modified inside the loop, you can hoist this check out of the loop:

```
if (2<=n && n <=100) {  
    for(int i=0; i<n ;i++) {
```

and similarly for the other loops as well.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, then consider accepting it.

Comment: sorry but can you tell me how check  if all numbers are even then divide each of them by 2 otherwise, you can not perform any more operations and print he maximum possible number of operations that can be performed. I write code but I can't ask question now